# Checking if variable set

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following which checks URL variables:

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1] || 0;
};
```

I want to set variables only if they are present in the URL.

Example URL:

```
http://myUrl.com/search?searchTerm=red
```

Example JS, which works correctly:

```
if(typeof $.urlParam('searchTerm') != 'undefined'){
    var searchTerm = $.urlParam('searchTerm');
}
```

However, if I try the following (checking for another variable) the code fails, yet with no error in the FF console:

```
if(typeof $.urlParam('storeSearch') != 'undefined'){
    var storeSearch = $.urlParam('storeSearch');
}
```

Is there a better way to check if a URL variable is set and then assign that value to a javascript variable?

Comment: Well, your `$.urlParam` returns `0` if no match is found. So why are you comparing to `typeof ... != 'undefined'`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a Type Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function can never return `undefined`, so the check you are using will never work correctly.

An immediate improvement would be to change the function to return `undefined` appropriately:

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return results[1]; // undefined if no match for capturing group 1
};
```

However, this will still not be good enough because if your regex does not match at all then `exec` returns `null` and `null[1]` will produce an error. So improve it further to:

```
$.urlParam = function(name) {
    var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
    return (results || undefined) && results[1];
};
```

`results || undefined` evaluates to either an array (which may or may not have an `[1]` element). If it resolves to `undefined`, then `undefined && results[1]` is also `undefined`. If it resolves to an array, then either `[1]` evaluates to the second element if one exists, or to `undefined` if it does not.

In all cases the final value is either `undefined` or the matched contents of the capturing group.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. TypeError: results is null results[1]

Comment: Also tried: if(typeof $.urlParam('storeSearch') !==null)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney: Indeed there was more to fix. updated the answer.

Comment: Wow! Works amazing! It's a learning curve, thanks for taking the time out, it's appreciated!